# JS Promise when looping through array of chrome.bookmarks.getChildren

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, promise, underscore.js

I'm developing a google chrome extension and I have to loop trough the nodes (folders) to check how many items I have within each folder. I'm suppling an item ID to the function `getBookmarksCount(ID)`. I'm having an issue to get a result from the main function the `console.log()` returns correct value at the point of logging.

Here is my code:

```js
const getBookmarksCount = (bmkNode) => {
    let nodes = []
    let result = 0

    new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.bookmarks.getChildren(bmkNode, (bmkChildren) => {

            _.each(bmkChildren, (item) => {
            
                // Check if the item is a bookmark link
                if (!(item.url === undefined || item.url === null)) {
                    nodes.push(item.title)
                }
                
            })
    
            resolve(_.size(nodes))

        })
        
    }).then((size) => {
        console.log(size) //The correct number of items is listed here eg. 6
        result = size
    })

    return result
}

//I'm suppling a parent folder ID the function should return number of children

getBookmarksCount(123) // eg. 6 -> at the moment returns 0
```

Here is my updated working version without Promise. `setTimeout()` is a dirty hack but works. Any suggestions how I can improve this function?

```js
const getBookmarksCount = (bmkNode) => {
let nodes = []

const getChildrenCount = (bmkNode) => {

    chrome.bookmarks.getChildren(bmkNode, (bmkChildren) => {
        
        _.each(bmkChildren, (item) => {

            // if is bookmark otherwise loop trough subfolder
            (!(item.url === undefined || item.url === null)) ? nodes.push(item.title): getChildrenCount(item.id)

        })

    })

    setTimeout(() => {
        $(`#counter_${bmkNode}`).html(_.size(nodes))
    }, 50)

}

getChildrenCount(bmkNode)

}

// HTML Template

<label class="label label-primary" id="counter_${item.id}">0</label>
```

Comment: Promises imply asynchronous code - you are not waiting for asynchronous code to complete before you `return result`

Comment: chrome.bookmarks.getChildren is an async function so I'm trying fo wrap it in promise...How to improve my code?

Comment: p.s. instead of `_.each`  and push, consider use of `_.filter` to extract the subset of legal array elements and `_.pluck` to get the title property of each.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Bravo in the comments, you are not really waiting for your code to execute. You are ever so close, though!

```
const getBookmarksCount = (bmkNode) => {
   return new Promise ((resolve) => {
      let nodes = []
      chrome.bookmarks.getChildren(bmkNode, (bmkChildren) => {
          _.each(bmkChildren, (item) => {
              // Check if the item is a bookmark link
              if (!(item.url === undefined || item.url === null)) {
                  nodes.push(item.title)
              }  
          })

          resolve(_.size(nodes))
      })
   })
}
getBookmarksCount(123).then(size => {
    console.log(size)
})
```

Note the `return new Promise` on the second line, which is a key difference from your provided snippet. By doing this, you wait to "return" here until you actually finish the async work and call `resolve`. Then, to get the value returned, you would do the same `.then` syntax you used but at the call of `getBookmarksCount`.

Hopefully that helps and, of course, also works!

Comment: This way will work but `getBookmarksCount` is a part of the template `<label class="label label-primary">${getBookmarksCount(item.id)}</label>` so will be better if returns value without needing then...

Comment: @Ben that's the whole point - you _can't_ return a value from a function that makes asynchronous calls.

Comment: @cgdibble what do you think about my update?

Comment: @Ben it's a horrible nasty hack.

Comment: you've removed the template example you had before.  Was that something built-in to Chrome plugins, or was it an external API like Angular, React, etc ?  Angular knows how to take a `Promise` in its templates, and they auto update when the promise is resolved.

Comment: @Alnitak I've added template example

Comment: @Ben I wouldn't do it the hacky way, that will make it harder to understand and debug in the future for sure. Why is it better if it doesn't return a promise? That adds a new element to the question that changes it quite a bit from just returning with a promise.